# Conditional meta_query and tax_query for wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

Depending on some variable, I need to get all posts or a list of posts filtered by a custom field.

I can get all posts and I can get the list of posts filtered by the custom field and tag with separate queries but I'm trying to combine the queries.

The single query returns the filtered list:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',                            
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'listing_status',
            'value' => array('active','sold'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $agentslug,
        ),
    )                        
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but I also might need the list unfiltered. I tried combining the queries:

```
$meta_query = array();
$tax_query = array();

if ( $agentslug ) {
    $meta_query[] = array(array(
        'key' => 'listing_status',
        'value' => array('active','sold'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    ));
    $tax_query[] = array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $agentslug,
    ));
}

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',                            
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query                  
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but they both return the full list.

Answer (score 3):

You are using 1 nested array to much

```
$meta_query = array();
$meta_query[] = array(array());
```

Acts the same as

```
$meta_query = array();
array_push( $meta_query, array(array()) )
```

And has the same  result as

```
$meta_query = array(array(array()));
```

Change

```
if ( $agentslug ) {
    $meta_query[] = array(array(
        'key' => 'listing_status',
        'value' => array('active','sold'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    ));
    $tax_query[] = array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $agentslug,
    ));
}
```

To

```
if ( $agentslug ) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'listing_status',
        'value' => array('active','sold'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    );
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $agentslug,
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made the changes but the results are the same, all posts are returned.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `var_dump($args)` to your question?

Comment: array(8) { ["post_type"]=> string(8) "listings" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["orderby"]=> string(4) "date" ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["posts_per_page"]=> string(1) "4" ["paged"]=> int(1) ["meta_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(14) "listing_status" ["value"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "active" [1]=> string(4) "sold" } ["compare"]=> string(2) "IN" } } ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["terms"]=> string(19) "johnny-dangerous" } } }

Comment: Hmm the arguments look good right now. That's strange